# Installing Kong API Gateway with External Postgres using Helm Chart

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes-helm, kong, kong-ingress

I have a Postgres Database running on Kubernetes cluster.

**kubectl get po -n kong**

```
NAME                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS       AGE
kong-postgres-pod                          1/1     Running            0              31m
```

**kubectl get svc -n kong**

```
NAME                                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                         AGE
postgres-kong-service                   ClusterIP      10.233.44.192   <none>        5432/TCP                        38m
```

Now I want to bind this postgres database with Kong API Gateway, which I am installing using Helm chart.

**Helm Installation:**

```
helm repo add kong https://charts.konghq.com 

helm repo update 

helm install kong-with-postgres --namespace kong kong/kong \
   --set ingressController.installCRDs=false \
   --set env.database=postgres \
   --set admin.enabled=true \
   --set admin.http.enabled=true \
   --set env.pg_host=postgres-kong-service.kong.svc.cluster.local \
   --set env.pg_user=postgres \
   --set env.pg_password=kong \
   --set env.pg_port=5432 \
   --set env.pg_database=postgres
```

It creates two more pods as shown below:

**kubectl get po -n kong**

```
NAME                                            READY   STATUS             RESTARTS      AGE
kong-with-postgres-kong-5486bb5774-n2cfs        0/2     Init:1/2           0             3m4s
kong-with-postgres-kong-init-migrations-g78tv   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   4 (63s ago)   3m4s
kong-postgres-pod                               1/1     Running            0             28m
```

Below are the logs for these PODs:

**kubectl logs -f kong-with-postgres-kong-init-migrations-g78tv -n kong**

```
Error: [PostgreSQL error] failed to retrieve PostgreSQL server_version_num: connection refused

Run with --v (verbose) or --vv (debug) for more details
```

**kubectl logs -f kong-with-postgres-kong-5486bb5774-n2cfs -n kong**

```
Defaulted container "ingress-controller" out of: ingress-controller, proxy, clear-stale-pid (init), wait-for-db (init)
Error from server (BadRequest): container "ingress-controller" in pod "kong-with-postgres-kong-5486bb5774-n2cfs" is waiting to start: PodInitializing
```

What value should I set for **env.pg_host** ?

What's wrong with my helm parameters?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The pg_host given by you looks fine for me.  First check the logs of post gres pod to know what is the reason for failure of connection. More likely it looks like the user might not have the host specified as % in the postgres - when the user was created.